# In SSIS XML config, in what places does Servername need to be modified?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssis

if you want to manually modify connection manager in package configured generated XML to a different server, exactly where (and in how many places) do you modify the server name? Also, what is the rationale for which places you modify this information?

q1. in the xml below, which i have generated by changing the server name in the connection manager and re-running property configurations, in order to change the server back manually by modifying the XML directly, it appears you would modify the servername after `Data Source =` and after

```
Package.Connections[StagingConn].Properties[ServerName]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>
```

**is this correct?**

q2. the xml below results from changing the connection manager itself and then regenerating the property configurations. the original server was

> NYCDSTGDWDB01\NADEVSTG1EDW

and the changed to server is

> NYGNACKENSON2\NADEV1EDW

what does the section Application 
`Name=SSIS-ExtractCRMStage_BusinessUnit-{8ECEE79B-793C-4E54-A659-C487265700DD}NYCDSTGDWDB01\NADEVSTG1EDW` 
used for and why was the servername not get changed in that place when i switched servers and regenerated the package configuration XML?

```
Path="\Package.Connections[StagingConn].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>**Data Source=**NYGNACKENSON2\NADEV1EDW;Initial Catalog=WeightWatchersStaging;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;
Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-ExtractCRMStage_BusinessUnit-{8ECEE79B-793C-4E54-A659-C487265700DD}NYCDSTGDWDB01\NADEVSTG1EDW.WeightWatchersStaging;</ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[StagingConn].Properties[Description]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue></ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[StagingConn].Properties[InitialCatalog]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>WeightWatchersStaging</ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[StagingConn].Properties[Name]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>StagingConn</ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[StagingConn].Properties[Password]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue></ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[StagingConn].Properties[ProtectionLevel]" ValueType="Int32"><ConfiguredValue>1</ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[StagingConn].Properties[RetainSameConnection]" ValueType="Boolean"><ConfiguredValue>0</ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[StagingConn].**Properties[ServerName]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>**NYGNACKENSON2\NADEV1EDW</ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[StagingConn].Properties[UserName]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue></ConfiguredValue></Configuration></DTSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If you have just selected `connection string` properties while generating xml configuration then you need to change the server name only in one location

```
   <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[localhost.Test].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=SSIS-Package-{15F05396-460E-4646-B9BD-A10EE11628A5}localhost.Test;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
```

Change the DataSource=*localhost*

else if you have selected all the properties in `Package Configuration Wizard` like in Connection String ,server ,name etc then you need to change at 2 places

```
1.Properties[ConnectionString] Change DataSource here and Properties[ServerName]
 change the configured value for it
```

2.Application name comes in the config file because you are having `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey` as the `protection level` for package .In this protection level only you can run your package in your system. If you try to share the SSIS package to some one else they won't be able to execute it as the package is `password protected` with a `key`   (which you see in the config file ) which can be decrypted only when you run the package from your system

Refer [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) article for various protection level used in SSIS